# Laravel 5.6 - How to execute scheduled kernel command only on production env?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

We only want the following command to run on the `production` environment, not the `staging`. We tried using the `--env:production flag` but that didn't work:

```
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel {
 ...
   protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule){
     $schedule->command('file:generate --env=production')
              ->daily()
              ->onOneServer();
   }
 ...
}
```

In laravel 5.8, to limit the task to a certain environment, there is a chainable `environments` like so:

```
$schedule->command('file:generate')
         ->daily()
         ->onOneServer()
         ->environments($env);
```

Any idea how we can run the command in 5.6 on `production` env?

Comment: Have you tried the "Truth Test Constraints" `->when(Closure);`? https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling#schedule-frequency-options, section "Truth Test Constraints"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One  can  check the environment before running commands

```
if (App::environment('production')) {
   $schedule->command('file:generate')
         ->daily();
   //run your commands here

}
```